# How to construct objects in one class from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, object, c#-3.0

I declared properties in the "FileData.cs" files. I want to assign the values for each property from another class "PdfMergerViewModel.cs".

FileData.cs

```
        public class FileData
        {
        private BatchData _batch;
        public FileData(BatchData batch)
        {
            this._batch = batch;
        }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string VersionNormalizedFileName { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public string Metadata { get; private set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public string Centerpoint { get; set; }
        public string BatchID { get; set; }
        public string RegionalPrefix { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string FunctionLocation { get; set; }
        public string KeyMap { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
        public string SendToGIS { get; set; }
        public string PipeBeforeFilename { get; set; }

        public IList<FileData> VersionFiles
        {
            get
            {
                return _batch.Files.Where(x => x.VersionNormalizedFileName == FileName && !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
            }
            private set { }
        }
```

PdfMergerViewModel.cs

```
        FileData fd = new FileData(new BatchData());
        void createOutputBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("D:/data.txt"))
            {
                String input;

                while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] stringArray = input.Split(',');
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to put the "fd" object inside the for loop and assign the values for each property in "FileData.cs". I don't know how to assign the value. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Multiple Lines are present in the "Data.Txt" file. The one line in "Data.txt" file looks like as follows:

```
"Centerpoint - Arkansas (Fixed)","Centerpoint SO - Arkansas","{$DOCUMENT ID}","61||","{$BATCH ID}","32601","{$REGIONAL PREFIX}","E","CITY","CUSHING","DATE","05/25/1945","FUNCTION LOCATION","X-SVCS","KEY MAP","","ORDER NUMBER","","STATE","AR","STREET NUMBER","819","STREET NAME","E BROADWAY","UNIT NUMBER","","SEND TO GIS","X","{$PIPE BEFORE FILENAME}","||","\\HOUKOFAX01\Client\Centerpoint Arkansas\7_9_2012\32601\819 E BROADWAY.pdf"
```

Previously "Dictionary" used. Now we are changing to object oriented approach. The following code is used when dictionary item is present. Now, instead of dictionary, I need to use the object oriented approach to assign the values in "FileData.cs" class.
Code which used Dictionary Item:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> item = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                item.Add(RemoveQuote(stringArray[i]), RemoveQuote(stringArray[i + 1]));
                i++;
            }
```

Instead of dictionary, "fd" object, I need to assign the values. I don't know how to assign the value. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what is the contents of a single line in data.txt file?

Comment: "Centerpoint - Arkansas (Fixed)","Centerpoint SO - Arkansas","{$DOCUMENT ID}","61||","{$BATCH ID}","32601","{$REGIONAL PREFIX}","E","CITY","CUSHING","DATE","05/25/1945","FUNCTION LOCATION","X-SVCS","KEY MAP","","ORDER NUMBER","","STATE","AR","STREET NUMBER","819","STREET NAME","E BROADWAY","UNIT NUMBER","","SEND TO GIS","X","{$PIPE BEFORE FILENAME}","||","\\HOUKOFAX01\Client\Centerpoint Arkansas\7_9_2012\32601\819 E BROADWAY.pdf"

Comment: Above is the single line in data.txt file

Comment: Update the question rather than a commment

Comment: I assume that you have many lines, could you explain if the values in the lines of data.txt are always in the same order?.

Comment: @Steve, The lines of data.txt is always in the same order. It looks like multiple lines. Actually, it is a single line. Also I updated my question by adding the line present in the data.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a List(Of FileData) to keep in memory every line you transform from the file, not just one FileData object.
Then you should find a mapping between the line read and slipt from the data.txt and the single properties of a FileData.

```
    List<FileData> listOfData = new List<FileData>();
    void createOutputBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
    { 
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("D:/data.txt")) 
        { 
            String input; 

            while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            { 
                FileData fd = new FileData(new BatchData()); 
                string[] stringArray = input.Split(','); 
                for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length - 1; i+=2) 
                { 
                     switch(stringArray[i])
                     {
                          case "{$BATCH ID}":
                             fd.BatchID = stringArray[i+1];
                             break;
                          // Other properties follow ..... 
                          case ......
                     }
                } 
                listOfData.Add(fd);
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming you have the name and value of the property on the text file, you could try using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = fd.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
propertyInfo.SetValue(fd, Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't have the name of the property, then it should at least be organized in a known order, otherwise it's not possible to set the properties dynamically.

If its in a known order, you could retrieve the FileData properties and manipulate them to fit the same order as the text file.

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(FileData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

//Possible Sort

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{

}
```

Comment: My thought too, but still need some translation from field name in txt file (STREET NUMBER) to property name in the class (StreetNumber).

Comment: Namespace reflection does not detecting propertyInfo.SetValue

Comment: The variable propertyInfo is an instance of System.Reflection.PropertyInfo, which does have the method SetValue.

Comment: @MateusArturSchneiders, How to set propertyName and propertyValue as it shows does not exist in the current context. Thanks.

Comment: propertyName would be name of the property from the FileData class such as "BatchID" and propertyValue would be just the value of that corresponding property in the file line, but that would be used in case you have this information on the text file. From the example line you posted, i don't think you have all the property names.

Comment: From the file example line, i don't think it will be doable to read the properties dynamically, you could try to use the mapping scheme that @Steve posted below.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileData fd = new FileData(new BatchData());
void createOutputBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("D:/data.txt"))
    {
       String input;    
       while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
            string[] stringArray = input.Split(',');
            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof (FileData).GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                  props[i].SetValue(fd, stringArray[i]);
            }
       }
   }
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to add reference to `System.Reflection`.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// EDITS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Well, the most correct solution, I think, is first to check what type is your property and only then make an assignment. You can use `if` statement:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    if(props[i].GetValue(m) is DateTime)
    {
        props[i].SetValue(m, DateTime.Parse(stringArray[i]));
    }
    else
    {
        if(props[i].GetValue(m) is bool)
        {
            props[i].SetValue(m, stringArray[i].Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
        else
        {
             props[i].SetValue(m, stringArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Or more elegant, especially if You have more than 3 different types in your class, `switch`:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    object type = props[i].PropertyType;
    switch(type.ToString())
    {
         case "System.String": props[i].SetValue(m, stringArray[i]); break;
         case "System.DateTime": props[i].SetValue(m, DateTime.Parse(stringArray[i])); break;
         case "System.Boolean": props[i].SetValue(m, stringArray[i].Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));break;
     }
}
...
```

Note: As You can see, You should use `type.ToString()` statement because `switch` expects value of integral type, and `props[i].GetType()` or `props[i].PropertyType` aren't such.

Comment: No Overload takes '0' arguments is shown in the setvalue line.

Comment: But you pass 2 arguments (`fd` - the object whose property value will be set and `stringArray[i]` - the value itself), not 0 ))). Are you sure you're making all right? P.S. I use .Net Framework v4.5 as target framework for my application, where I tested the code. May be `SetValue` function is different in different framework versions. What .Net Framework version do you use?

Comment: I use .Net 4.0 framework. It shows obj, obj value and object index.Not 0 means I can't able to figure out exactly. What argument I need to put after the stringArray[i]. Thanks.

Comment: @John, Well [documenataion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) says that **index** is _Optional index values for indexed properties. For nonindexed properties, this value should be a null reference._ I suggest You should just pass `null` as third argument.

Comment: Previously I used item.Add(RemoveQuote(stringArray[i]), RemoveQuote(stringArray[i + 1])) for removing quotes when Dictionary is used. So, how can I use the above function in props[i].SetValue(fd, stringArray[i],null); Thanks.

Comment: @John, Just like before, I guess. Instead of `stringArray[i]` just pass `RemoveQuote(stringArray[i])`. Like `props[i].SetValue(fd, RemoveQuote(stringArray[i]), null);` If, of course, I understood You correctly and every come separated value of one line in your **Data.txt** file is corresponding to some property of your `FileData` class and `RemoveQuote("some string")` function just returns `some string`.

Comment: When i am assigning the values using the above code, for boolean and datetime, it is throwing error as "Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.boolean'." Similarly to datetime. How can I solve this for boolean and datetime type. Thanks.